# Forcibly break a for loop in sh

Tags: bash, zsh, sh

If I run a for loop on the command line in sh, and I press control-C, it usually cancels the current running process, so I need to hold ^C until the shell itself catches it and breaks the loop. Is there a way to break current process *and* the loop immediately?

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way I know would be to suspend the foreground job (`^Z`), then kill it using the job id (`kill %<JOB_ID>`).

Example:

```
[me@host]$ while [ : ]; do less /etc/motd; done   # Ctrl-C can't kill this
```

After a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>

```
[1]+  Stopped                 less /etc/motd

[me@host]$ kill %1
[me@host]$
```

The number within the brackets (`[1]`) at the beginning of the suspension message gives you the job id.

You can also list out ids of suspended jobs using the the `jobs` command.